# Need Start and Stop times for GCP VM instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Using Google cloud AP, I want to retrieve below  data about VM instances

Start times and stop time for provided google instances in the last one month.

Will it be possible

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with Google Cloud AP?

For the other hand you can obtain the VM's activity on [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview), for the information you require go to Cloud Logging page, [convert to advance filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) and you can apply this query for start operations:

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
"compute.instances.start"
```

And this for stop operations:

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
"compute.instances.stop"
```

You can apply a date and time filter for better results.

Also you can get the same information with [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud):

> gcloud logging read "jsonPayload.event_subtype =
> compute.instances.stop"

and

> gcloud logging read "jsonPayload.event_subtype =
> compute.instances.start"

For more advance options check the [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/activity-logs)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You . This helped

I can use logging api

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list

to retrieve start and stop times for VM resources

Comment: Hi, if the answer was useful you can accept it on the post, with this if another user have a similar question he will be able to find the information more easily.